# How to close a TcpClient opened in a Thread Properly

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I am connected to `TcpClient` with a `Thread`. Now connection of `TcpClient` is opening properly in the thread but closing of the `TcpClient` and the thread is not happening properly. I dont know why.

Here is the thread that I am starting:

```
 private System.Threading.Thread _thread;
 private ManualResetEvent _shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false); 

_thread = new Thread(DoWork);
_thread.Start();
```

And here is the `TcpClient` connection:

```
private void DoWork()
{
while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
{                           
    try
    {
        client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip),intport));
        //Say thread to sleep for 1 secs.
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the error here.
        client.Close();
        continue;
    }
    try
    {
        using (stream = client.GetStream())
        {

           byte[] notify = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello");
           stream.Write(notify, 0, notify.Length);

            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
            {
                int numBytesRead = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                if (numBytesRead > 0)
                {
                    line= Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, numBytesRead);
                }
            }
            ...
```

And now here is the code to close and restart the thread and `TcpClient`:

```
 _shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0);
 _thread.Abort();

 //Start Again
 _thread = new Thread(DoWork);
 _thread.Start();
```

Please help me to stop and start the thread and `TcpClient` properly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Declare _shutdownEvent as AutoResetEvent.

```
AutoResetEvent _shutdownEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

Remove the outer while loop in the Dowork method

```
private void DoWork()
    {
        try
        {
            client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), intport));
            //Say thread to sleep for 1 secs.
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the error here.
            client.Close();
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            using (stream = client.GetStream())
            {
                byte[] notify = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello");
                stream.Write(notify, 0, notify.Length);

                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
                {
                    int numBytesRead = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    if (numBytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        line = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, numBytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();
            if (client != null)
                client.Close();
        }        
    }
```

Use `_shutdownEvent.Set()` to signal the event.

```
_shutdownEvent.Set(); //Set, not Wait
//_thread.Abort(); //and you don't have to abort the thread since it will end gracefully after it break out of the while loop
while (_thread.IsAlive) ; //wait until the first thread exit

//Start Again
_thread = new Thread(DoWork);
_thread.Start();
```

Comment: I am not able to restart the `TcpClient();` client with the given code

Comment: `_thread = new Thread(DoWork);
_thread.Start();` with this code i am not able to get breakpoint at Dowork() method..

Comment: @HansPassant Can you please guide me to the appropriate way..Thnks

Comment: @HansPassant since ManualResetEvent's state will not be reset to non-signaled after being Wait successfully. So we need an AutoResetEvent.

Comment: But i am not able to start the Thread again..`_thread = new Thread(DoWork);
_thread.Start();`

Comment: ARE is *not* a solution, there is no guarantee that the active worker thread is going to call WaitOne() before the new thread.  Very nasty threading race bug since it usually works fine, impossible to debug.

Comment: admittedly there are several assumptions in the code, 1st is the worker thread is inside the while loop busy reading from network stream, 2nd is it does not call WaitOne which might cause a deadlock that both threads are waiting something that never happen(and thus both get freezed).

Comment: @kennyzx I am sorry if it is late to tell that i want the `Networkstream` to be refreshed every minute so that if any disconnection happens due to not availability of Network connection then it should refresh or restart

Comment: @shubhamHegdey join this http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61905/wpf-stackpanel